# Which Database Software Is Suitable For Data Historian?

Tags: sql-server, database, olap

My project is a Data Historian System.
which reads data(contains 10,0000 records) every 5 second from sources and inserts into database for reports and analyses.the format of data is simple(iNT, INT, Float, DateTime).
should i have to use OLAP Database Approach?
is SQL Server  suitable for this case?
thanks...

Comment: Too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds crazy inefficient:   there are several alternative approaches you might want to consider:

1. Use an update trigger to write table inserts / changes to a history
   table.   You should add the change date to the history table so that
   the "effective" record for any particular datetime can be
   determined.
2. In SQL Server, a timestamp column can be used to drive record
   version identification, and you can use the same kind of polling
   approach you suggested, but saving only new / changed records.
3. SQL Server has a Change Data Capture to identify changed rows:
       details [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/#targetText=Change%20Data%20Capture%20records%20INSERTs,esoteric%20chopped%20salad%20of%20XML.).